# How to solve the error: Call to a member function row() on string?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I set up a web application with a registration form. When I try to insert the data into the database through this form, I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function row() on string in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hopital\application\modules\patient\controllers\patient.php:361
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hopital\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(360):
> Patient->addNew() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\hopital\index.php(208):
> require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hopital\application\modules\patient\controllers\patient.php
> on line 361.

**Controller**

```
if (empty($id)) {     // Adding New Patient
                if ($this->ion_auth->email_check($email)) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'Cette adresse email est déjà enregistré dans la base données');
                    redirect('patient/addNewView');
                } else {
                    $dfg = 5;
                    $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $dfg);
//                    $ion_user_id=this->db-get_where('users', array('email'=> $email))->row()['id'];
//                    $ion_user_id = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email))->row()['id'];
                    $ion_user_id = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email))->row()->id;
                    if ($ion_user_id) {

                    $ion_user_id = $ion_user_id->row()->id; // This is the line 361 withe has that error
                    }
                    $this->patient_model->insertPatient($data);
                  $patient_user_id = $this->db->get_where('pa;tient', array('email' => $email))->row()->id;
                    $id_info = array('ion_user_id' => $ion_user_id);
                    $this->patient_model->updatePatient($patient_user_id, $id_info);
                    $this->hospital_model->addHospitalIdToIonUser($ion_user_id, $this->hospital_id);

                    if (!empty($sms)) {
                        $this->sms->sendSmsDuringPatientRegistration($patient_user_id);
                    }


                    $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback', 'Ajouté');
                }
```

**View**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">  <?php echo lang('register_new_patient'); ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body row">
                <form role="form" action="patient/addNew" class="clearfix" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('categorie'); ?></label>
     <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="categorie" value='' id="p_category">
        <option value=""> Sélectionner catégorie</option>
       <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
        <?php
  $selected = !empty($setval) && $category->category == set_value('category');
  $selected = $selected || !empty($patient->category) && $category->category == $patient->category
       ?>
 <option value="<?= $category->category ?>" <?= $selected ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $category->category; ?> </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>

 </div>

   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('name'); ?></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
   </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('email'); ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 cat-container" data-id="Femme">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('name_husband'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_Us" id="nameUs" placeholder="">

        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('number_pregnancy'); ?></label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number_pregnancy" id="nbreEnfants" placeholder="">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('password'); ?></label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="">
   </div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('address'); ?></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('andtecedentMed'); ?></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="andtecedentMed" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('andtecedentFam'); ?></label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="andtecedentFam" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('taille'); ?></label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="taille" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('poids'); ?></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="poids" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('phone'); ?></label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="exampleInputEmail1" value='' placeholder="">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('sex'); ?></label>
   <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="sex" value=''>

    <option value="Masculin" <?php
       if (!empty($patient->sex)) {
        if ($patient->sex == 'Masculin') {
          echo 'selected';
        }
       }
       ?> > Masculin </option>
    <option value="Féminin" <?php
       if (!empty($patient->sex)) {
       if ($patient->sex == 'Féminin') {
          echo 'selected';
           }
         }
      ?> > Féminin </option>
    <option value="Autres" <?php
       if (!empty($patient->sex)) {
         if ($patient->sex == 'Autres') {
             echo 'selected';
            }
          }
       ?> > Autres </option>
  </select>
</div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label><?php echo lang('birth_date'); ?></label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium default-date-picker" type="text" name="birthdate" value="" placeholder="" readonly="">      
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('blood_group'); ?></label>
                        <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="bloodgroup" value=''>
                            <?php foreach ($groups as $group) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $group->group; ?>" <?php
                                if (!empty($patient->bloodgroup)) {
                                    if ($group->group == $patient->bloodgroup) {
                                        echo 'selected';
                                    }
                                }
                                ?> > <?php echo $group->group; ?> </option>
                                    <?php } ?> 
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">    
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('doctor'); ?></label>
                        <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single"  name="doctor" value=''> 
                          <option value=""> </option>
                         <?php foreach ($doctors as $doctor) { ?>                                        
                         <option value="<?php echo $doctor->id; ?>"><?php echo $doctor->name; ?> </option>
                            <?php } ?> 
                        </select>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group last col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Charger image</label>
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                            <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                            <img src="//www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt="" />
                         </div>
                   <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
                   <div>
                <span class="btn btn-white btn-file">
                  <span class="fileupload-new"><i class="fa fa-paper-clip"></i> Selectionner image</span>
                  <span class="fileupload-exists"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Changer</span>
                   <input type="file" class="default" name="img_url"/>
                 </span>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Enlever</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--
                    <div class="form-group last col-md-6">
                        <div style="text-align:center;" class="col-md-12">
                            <video id="video" width="200" height="200" autoplay></video>
                            <div class="snap" id="snap">Capture Photo</div>
                            <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
                            Right click on the captured image and save. Then select the saved image from the left side's Select Image button.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    -->


                    <!-- <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sms" value="sms"> <?php echo lang('send_sms') ?><br>
                    </div> -->


                    <section class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right"><?php echo lang('submit'); ?></button>
                    </section>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

**Model**

```
function insertPatient($data) {
        $data1 = array('hospital_id' => $this->session->userdata('hospital_id'));
        $data2 = array_merge($data, $data1);
        $this->db->insert('patient', $data2);
    }
```

I used JavaScript to differentiate pregnant women from other categories of patients:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.cat-container').hide();

        $(document.body).on('change', '#p_category', function () {

            var v = $("#p_category option:selected").val();
            if (v == 'Femme enceinte') {
                $('.cat-container').show();
            } else {
                $('.cat-container').hide();
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: `$ion_user_id` already contains just the id, it is not the database query. `$ion_user_id->row()->id;` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do here?:

```
$ion_user_id = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email))->row()->id;
if ($ion_user_id) {
  $ion_user_id = $ion_user_id->row()->id; // This is the line 361 withe has that error
}
```

The logic is basically:

1. Get the ID value from the data
2. If the ID value exists
3. Update the ID value to the ID value

Aside from the fact that the *value* doesn't hold a reference back to the data source *of* the value, attempting to set a value to *its own value* is unnecessary.  Just remove that `if` block entirely:

```
$ion_user_id = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email))->row()->id;
```

Comment: @Dacid when I remove it, i obtain this error message: ***Severity: Avertissement

Message: Attempt to read property "id" on array

 file name: controllers/patient.php

 line: 359***

Comment: @DELARUELLELUMBIDI: Maybe you want `row()['id']` instead of `row()->id`, exactly like you do in the lines of code just before that?  Why do you perform the same operation in two different ways in the first place?  What was the reason for that change?

Comment: This error confuses me. I used row()['id'] as you say but it was the same error.